Can this pattern connect trigonometry and repeating decimals?
I have observed a cyclical pattern between the tangent function and repeating decimals.
Consider the following function:
$f(x)=\tan(\frac{10^{9d}-1}{x})^\circ$,
where,
$x$ is any non-zero integer but not divisible by $2$ or $5$,
$rep(1/x)$ is the repetend of $\frac{1}{x}$,
$d$ is the period or length of $rep(1/x)$,
$\frac{10^{9d}-1}{x}=\sum_{k=0}^{8} rep(1/x) \cdot 10^{kd}$

For $x=1$,
$rep(1/1)=9$, and, $d=1$, because $1/1=0.\overline{9}$
So,
$f(1)=\tan(\frac{10^{9\cdot1}-1}{1})^\circ=\tan(\frac{-9\pi}{20})=\tan(-81^\circ)$

For $x=3$,
$rep(1/3)=3$, and, $d=1$, because $1/3=0.\overline{3}$
So,
$f(3)=\tan(\frac{10^{9\cdot1}-1}{3})^\circ=\tan(\frac{-3\pi}{20})=\tan(-27^\circ)$

For $x=7$,
$rep(1/7)=142857$, and, $d=6$, because $1/7=0.\overline{142857}$
So,
$f(7)=\tan(\frac{10^{9\cdot6}-1}{7})^\circ=\tan(\frac{-7\pi}{20})=\tan(-63^\circ)$

For $x=9$,
$rep(1/9)=1$, and, $d=1$, because $1/9=0.\overline{1}$
So,
$f(9)=\tan(\frac{10^{9\cdot1}-1}{9})^\circ=\tan(\frac{-\pi}{20})=\tan(-9^\circ)$

For $x=11$,
$rep(1/11)=09$, and, $d=2$, because $1/11=0.\overline{09}$
So,
$f(11)=\tan(\frac{10^{9\cdot2}-1}{11})^\circ=\tan(\frac{\pi}{20})=\tan(9^\circ)$

For $x=13$,
$rep(1/13)=076923$, and, $d=6$, because $1/13=0.\overline{076923}$
So,
$f(13)=\tan(\frac{10^{9\cdot6}-1}{13})^\circ=\tan(\frac{7\pi}{20})=\tan(63^\circ)$

For $x=17$,
$rep(1/17)=0588235294117647$, and, $d=16$, because $1/17=0.\overline{0588235294117647}$
So,
$f(17)=\tan(\frac{10^{9\cdot16}-1}{17})^\circ=\tan(\frac{3\pi}{20})=\tan(27^\circ)$

For $x=19$,
$rep(1/19)=052631578947368421$, and, $d=18$, because $1/19=0.\overline{052631578947368421}$
So,
$f(19)=\tan(\frac{10^{9\cdot18}-1}{19})^\circ=\tan(\frac{9\pi}{20})=\tan(81^\circ)$

For the subsequent values of $x$, the tangent function starts repeating:
$f(1)=f(21)=f(41)=f(61)=f(81)=f(101)=\dots=\tan(\frac{-9\pi}{20})=\tan(-81^\circ)$
$f(3)=f(23)=f(43)=f(63)=f(83)=f(103)=\dots=\tan(\frac{-3\pi}{20})=\tan(-27^\circ)$
$f(7)=f(27)=f(47)=f(67)=f(87)=f(107)=\dots=\tan(\frac{-7\pi}{20})=\tan(-63^\circ)$
$f(9)=f(29)=f(49)=f(69)=f(89)=f(109)=\dots=\tan(\frac{-\pi}{20})=\tan(-9^\circ)$
$f(11)=f(31)=f(51)=f(71)=f(91)=f(111)=\dots=\tan(\frac{\pi}{20})=\tan(9^\circ)$
$f(13)=f(33)=f(53)=f(73)=f(93)=f(113)=\dots=\tan(\frac{7\pi}{20})=\tan(63^\circ)$
$f(17)=f(37)=f(57)=f(77)=f(97)=f(117)=\dots=\tan(\frac{3\pi}{20})=\tan(27^\circ)$
$f(19)=f(39)=f(59)=f(79)=f(99)=f(119)=\dots=\tan(\frac{9\pi}{20})=\tan(81^\circ)$

We can also generalize this pattern to include negative values of $x$.
For any whole number $m$,
$f(10-9+20m)=\tan(\frac{-9\pi}{20})=\tan(-81^\circ)=f(-10-9-20m)$
$f(10-7+20m)=\tan(\frac{-3\pi}{20})=\tan(-27^\circ)=f(-10-7-20m)$
$f(10-3+20m)=\tan(\frac{-7\pi}{20})=\tan(-63^\circ)=f(-10-3-20m)$
$f(10-1+20m)=\tan(\frac{-\pi}{20})=\tan(-9^\circ)=f(-10-1-20m)$
$f(10+1+20m)=\tan(\frac{\pi}{20})=\tan(9^\circ)=f(-10+1-20m)$
$f(10+3+20m)=\tan(\frac{7\pi}{20})=\tan(63^\circ)=f(-10+3-20m)$
$f(10+7+20m)=\tan(\frac{3\pi}{20})=\tan(27^\circ)=f(-10+7-20m)$
$f(10+9+20m)=\tan(\frac{9\pi}{20})=\tan(81^\circ)=f(-10+9-20m)$


Interestingly,
$\frac{\pi}{20}+\frac{3\pi}{20}+\frac{7\pi}{20}+\frac{9\pi}{20}=\pi$
$9^\circ+27^\circ+63^\circ+81^\circ=180^\circ$ (period of the tangent function)


What explains this pattern? Why does it hold for all $x$ ?

Before you leave:
$\tan9^\circ \cdot \tan81^\circ=1=\tan27^\circ \cdot \tan63^\circ$ (complementary angles)
$\tan9^\circ \cdot \tan27^\circ \cdot \tan63^\circ \cdot \tan81^\circ=\tan45^\circ$  (this equation contains all the digits $1$ to $9$)
$\tan9^\circ+\tan27^\circ+\tan63^\circ+\tan81^\circ=4\sqrt{5}$  (this equation also contains digits $1$ to $9$)
$(\tan9^\circ+\tan27^\circ+\tan63^\circ+\tan81^\circ)^{2}=80$



To further explore the beauty of $9,27,63,81$, I would suggest you to read this post: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/836801

If you review your post, there is no question here. What are you asking?

And for example in your demonstration for $f(3)$, somehow you replace a sum of positive things with $-27$. I don't see what's going on there

$f(3)=\tan(\sum_{k=0}^{8} rep(1/3) \cdot 10^{k})=\tan(333333333)=-0.50952544949443=\tan(-27)$
Now do you understand?

You are executing tangent in degrees instead of radians. And the pattern you see is just the result of tangent having period 180.

From a casual skim, it looks to me like the tangent function itself isn't actually doing anything. Instead, you're "simply" reducing the rep-sums modulo $180$ (and shifting values over $90$ back by $180$). It's true that the tangents of the corresponding values (taken as degrees) are equal, but introducing the trig function is unnecessarily complicated. This is a number-theoretical calculation, not a trigonometric one.

But this pattern is not seen with sine or cosine function. Only tangent function produces such a pattern.

@DevSharma: "But this pattern is not seen with sine or cosine function. Only tangent function produces such a pattern." I suspect this has to do with tangent having a period of $180$ (in degrees), while sine and cosine have a period of $360$ (in degrees). I haven't looked hard enough at your calculations to be able to say why these periods matter.

There is no need for so many edits! Please keep them to a minimum.

@DevSharma: Finding patterns and connections is what math is all about, so I encourage your continued explorations. That said, many (most? all?) of your recently-added observations about $9$, $27$, $63$, $81$ have no direct relevance to your original question. Having already received a comprehensive answer to that question, festooning it with irrelevancies may seem harmless, but: Each edit "bumps" a question to the top of the site's queue, hence bumps-down questions from people who need help. Math.SE is not a blogging platform; please find another outlet for your brainstorms. ... Good luck!

@Blue, I'll be careful next time. By the way, did you check out the last line of this post? It links to my another post on physics stack exchange. It's a deeper connection of $9,27,63,81$, tangents, logarithms, $\pi,e$, arithmetic, algebra, etc.

Let
$$
a(x)=\frac{10^{9d}-1}{x}
$$
where $x$ is a positive integer such that $1/x$ has a non terminating decimal fraction and $d$ is the period of repetition of that decimal fraction.
Let the last digit of $x$ in decimal be one of the digits $1,3,7,9.$
Note that $a(x)$ in decimal is $9$ repetitions of a block of $d$ digits.
Therefore the sum of digits is $9$ times the sum of digits in one repetend, so $a(x)$ is divisible by $9.$
We can therefore define $h(x)=\frac19 a(x),$ and $h(x)$ will always be an integer.
It follows that
$$xh(x)=\frac19 xa(x)= \frac{10^{9d}-1}{9},$$
which is an integer whose decimal representation is a string of at least nine $1$s, so it ends with the digits $11$, so
$$ xh(x) \equiv -9 \pmod{20}.$$
Consider the case $x\equiv1\pmod{20}.$
Then
$$h(x)\equiv xh(x)\equiv -9 \pmod{20}.$$
Now consider
$x\equiv-1\pmod{20}.$
Then
$$h(x)\equiv -xh(x)\equiv 9 \pmod{20}.$$
We can combine the two cases as follows:
if $x\equiv\pm1\pmod{20}$
then
$$h(x)\equiv \pm xh(x)\equiv \mp9 \pmod{20}.$$
Next, if  $x\equiv\pm3\pmod{20}$
then $7x\equiv\pm21\equiv\pm1 \pmod{20}$ and
$$h(x)\equiv \pm 7xh(x)\equiv \mp7\cdot9 \equiv\mp3\pmod{20}.$$
But if  $x\equiv\pm7\pmod{20}$
then $3x\equiv\pm21\equiv\pm1 \pmod{20}$ and
$$h(x)\equiv \pm 3xh(x)\equiv \mp3\cdot9 \equiv\mp7\pmod{20}.$$
And  if  $x\equiv\pm9\pmod{20}$
then $9x\equiv\pm81\equiv\pm1 \pmod{20}$ and
$$h(x)\equiv \pm 9xh(x)\equiv \mp9\cdot9 \equiv\mp1\pmod{20}.$$
We can convert a congruence modulo $20$ to congruences modulo $180$ by scaling everything up by a factor of $9.$ Let’s do this for the congruences with $h(x)$ on the left-hand end.
Since $9h(x)=a(x)$ the results are:
If $x\equiv\pm1\pmod{20}$,
then
$a(x)\equiv \mp81 \pmod{180}.$
If $x\equiv\pm3\pmod{20}$,
then
$a(x)\equiv \mp27 \pmod{180}.$
If $x\equiv\pm7\pmod{20}$,
then
$a(x)\equiv \mp63 \pmod{180}.$
If $x\equiv\pm9\pmod{20}$,
then
$a(x)\equiv \mp9 \pmod{180}.$
Then since $f(x)=\tan(a(x)^\circ)$ and since the tangent function has period $180^\circ,$ you will always have $f(x)=f(y)$ whenever $x\equiv y\pmod{20}$ and the last digit of $x$ in decimal is $1,3,7,9.$

This is an interesting way to explain. By the way, were you surprised to see this pattern? I was.

There is quite a lot that goes into this repetitive pattern to make it work. It relies on fact that $10^{9d}-1$ is congruent to $-80$ modulo $180;$ that’s not too difficult because $10^n\equiv-80\pmod{180}$ for every integer $n$ larger than $1$. But you need $9$ terms in your sum—not $8$, not $10$—to get the necessary factor of $9$ without which the pattern doesn’t work. Maybe to a number theorist this is all obvious, but I had to work to figure it out. So yes, it’s surprising.

Then there’s the happy historical accident that the Babylonians liked base $60$ and decided there should be $360$ degrees in a circle. If we used grads instead of degrees the period of tan would be $200$ grads rather than $180$ degrees and the pattern modulo $180$ would not come to light through a trig function.

David said "$10^{9d} -1$ is congruent to $-80$ modulo $180$". Just to correct, David meant "$10^{9d} $ is congruent to $-80$ modulo $180$".

That’s right, I meant to leave out the $-1$ but forgot. Later when I wrote $10^n$ I wrote it correctly. Too bad it cannot be corrected in place now.

Not an answer, but an attempt to re-state the question.
Some observations:

For rational $s$ (strictly) between $0$ and $1$, with a repetend of length $d$ that starts immediately after the decimal point, $rep(s)=(10^d-1)s$.
If integer $n>1$ is not divisible by $2$ or $5$, then $s=1/n$ is of the sort described in $(1)$.
For $n$ as in $(2)$, we can write $$\sum_{k=0}^8rep(1/n)10^{kd}=rep(1/n)\frac{10^{9d}-1}{10^d-1}=\frac{10^{9d}-1}{n} \tag{$\star$}$$
OP associates $n$ with the value of $(\star)$ reduced modulo $180$, but shifts results greater than $90$ back by $180$, so that all results lie between $-90$ and $90$. (Effectively, we apply $\operatorname{atan}(\tan(\cdot))$ to $(\star)$, treating the numbers as degrees. This comports with OP's use of the tangent function to describe the association; however, the introduction of trig functions is a bit of a distraction from the number-theoretical pattern in play.) The shift doesn't affect OP's ultimate point —which is that the values are cyclic— but it makes for a nicer-looking set of values. I'll use "$\bmod'$" to indicate this adjusted reduction.

Thus, defining
$$g(n) = \frac{10^{9d}-1}{n}\bmod' 180 \qquad (d := \text{length of repetend of $1/n$}) \tag1$$
OP has observed
$$\begin{align}
g(\phantom{1}3) = g(23) =\cdots=g(103) &\;=\; -27 \\
g(\phantom{1}7) = g(27) =\cdots=g(\phantom{1}87) &\;=\;  -63 \\
g(\phantom{1}9) = g(29) =\cdots=g(\phantom{1}89) &\;=\;  -\phantom{9}9 \\
g(11) = g(31)= \cdots = g(\phantom{1}91) &\;=\; +\phantom{9}9 \\
g(13) = g(33)= \cdots = g(\phantom{1}93) &\;=\; +63 \\
g(17) = g(37)= \cdots = g(\phantom{1}97) &\;=\; +27 \\
g(19) = g(39)= \cdots = g(\phantom{1}99) &\;=\; +81 \\
g(21) = g(41)= \cdots = g(101) &\;=\; -81
\end{align} \tag2$$
I'll note that, by identifying $1$ with $0.999\ldots$ (a rational with length-$1$ repetend that starts immediately after the decimal place), we can define $g(1)=(10^{9\cdot 1}-1)/1 \bmod' 180 =-81$, allowing us summarize OP's observations as
$$\begin{align}
g(10\pm 9+20m) &\;=\; \pm81 \\
g(10\pm 7+20m) &\;=\; \pm27 \\
g(10\pm 3+20m) &\;=\;  \pm 63 \\
g(10\pm 1+20m) &\;=\;  \pm\phantom{9}9
\end{align} \tag3$$
as integer $m$ ranges from $0$ to $4$ (sometimes $5$; I'll confirm that the pattern holds up to at least $m=1000$).
This raises the question:

What explains this pattern (and shows that it holds for all $m$)?


Thanks for your insights! I have edited my post based on your insights.
